# How to prevent Subversion from merging binary files?

Tags: svn, version-control

We have the need to keep .dlls in our repository. Our team experiences SVN conflicts on .dll files quite frequently and it is super annoying.  For some reason, even though the mime type of the .dlls are set to application/octet-stream, svn is still trying to merge them.

From what I found [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s02.html) (which I swear the way things used to be) it says that as long as the mime type isn't text, svn will not try to merge them.  But looking at my dlls tells me that svn is merging my application/octet-stream files too (at least I am assuming SVN is merging, not sure why there would be a conflict without a merge).  Why the heck would svn try to merge a binary file?  It's just stupid...

Anyone come across this problem?

My aim is to find a solution that allows binary files to be part of the repository, but never be conflicted.  I want SVN to just replace with the newest binary and call it good.

Please don't discuss why I should or should not be putting binary files in the repository - I have to and don't want conflict problems.

As a FYI: I use both Tortoise 1.5.0 and Ankh.

Comment: Not an answer, just a restatement of the policy that appears to be violated in your environment: http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#binary-files

Comment: How can you see that it's trying to merge them? A conflict is not proof that it's trying to merge them

Comment: I am just assuming they are trying to merge, because some updates do not cause conflicts and some do.  I want the conflicts to stop - not sure what the point of conflicts are if you can't compare/merge

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that policy Michael.  I had found that before I posted, and it doesn't say anything about conflicting binaries

Comment: There is a commit-hook which prevents checking in binary files that you do not have a lock for.  svn:lock will tell AnkhSVN to auto-lock binary files.  As a side-effect, if you have a file locked, another person won't be able to modify and check-in this binary without checking the file out.  Meanwhile, you have it checked out.  Very similar to Source-Safe or TFS.  But you can steal the lock if needed. [pre-commit-hook](http://www.gtwiki.org/mwiki/index.php?title=SVN_Locking).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure that I understand you correctly, let's recapitulate:

- you have binary files checked into svn
- these files can change both client-side and in the repository
- whenever both are changed, the changes from the repository should 'win'

AFAIK, the svn way to do that would be:

- run 'svn update --accept theirs-full' on the binary files
- run a regular 'svn update' on the whole local copy

I do not think this can be done in one command, and I also do not think it should be doable in one command, as that first command can lose valuable data.

Comment: The files never change in the repository, they obviously change from a client updating that file in the repository.  Since they are binary (for instance a word document or diagram) they should NEVER be merged, just replaced.  Maybe I described this problem wrong but all I want to be able to do is have svn never try to merge and just get the newest version on binary files

Comment: That's exactly what this answer describes; the --accept theirs-full throws away any local changes when there are incoming changes. This means that if you have a modified Word document, and someone else changed it, and you svn update --accept theirs-full, your version is lost, and updated with the one from your colleague

Answer (score 1):

If the file was changed on the server and locally you'll obviously get a conflict. Of course updating the working copy includes updating the binary files as they are part of the revisions. This doesn't mean svn tries to merge them, but you'll definitely get a conflict. If those files are changed frequently I guess they are generated frequently -- possibly even compiler output files. Such files should not be in the repository at all.

If you need to archive release binaries (or similar) you should do this on a tag or release branch but not on trunk.

Comment: Tagging the source should be enough to recreate the binaries. Archiving binaries isn't a task for source control.

Comment: While I completely agree with this companies / managers seem to think differently. At least from my experience, hence the comment.

Comment: You might not want to recompile core libraries very often.  So in those cases I think it makes sense to put dlls in svn.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question - I have the need to put binaries in svn without making a tag or trunk.  This also doesn't explain why sometimes they wouldn't conflict and just get replaced, but other times they do conflict.  Any more ideas?

Comment: Maybe you should explain *why* you have a need to put binaries in trunk. That way it might be possible to find other solutions for your issue. If you frequently get conflicts with the binaries your storage model seems to be unsuited for your problem.

As for the other question: if there are no conflicts (i.e. both files are identical on a binary level) they get replaced. If you rebuild the dll and the result is exactly the same as the file in svn you won't get a conflict when the file is updated in svn (as it was only changed at one location).

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem with certain files.

CVS handles this problem very well, but unfortunately my company is moving to Subversion.

Certain config files are modified by our app everytime you run it, but when the developers check in new changes, we want them to always overite the users repository.

In the `.CVSwrappers` file, put `*.fileext -k b -m COPY`. This tells CVS to always make a backup copy of the file in the local repository and download the new version when there are conflicts.  So elegant.

There is no equivalent setup for SVN.  If anyone knows how, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it's trying to merge them?  It sounds more like you are getting a conflict because subversion doesn't know how to merge them (which you don't want it to do anyway).

What exactly do you want to happen if you have a locally modified dll and someone commits the same dll before you do?  What do you expect to happen?  This is obviously a conflict and subversion doesn't know if you want it to use your dll or their dll.

Comment: Since they are binary files I would want svn to update them, that's it.  No conflicts, no trying to merge - nothing.  Just replace it with the newest one.

Comment: Well in that case you might be able to write a pre-commit hook-script that checks for a conflict and if it finds one, resolves it using the more recent file.

Unfortunately I have never written a hook-script so I can't be of much help there.

Comment: A pre-commit hook-script cannot fix this, because this is a server-side script. The conflicts and merging happen when updating on the client.

Answer (score -1):

These dll files, are they build output from the actual projects?

If that's the case, they shouldn't be put in svn at all. Subversion should contain the source files, and a build server / dev box can build the dlls from there.

Comment: I would rather keep this on topic - how to prevent conflicted binaries

Comment: Not versioning build output when there's no need is a great way to prevent conflicted binaries.
You cannot prevent conflicts if both your copy and the copy on the server have changed.